# Accessing loop variable in file lookup path

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to dynamically read file content inside for loop in template. But it fails as soon as i try to use `host` variable inside file path.

Some background:

- There're three entries in `groups.docker_hosts`.
- All files it's trying to read exist and are readable.
- Each file has content of `file content xx` where `xx` is host index

For instance this example works fine:

```
    template.j2
    {% for host in groups.docker_hosts %}
        "{{lookup('file', '{{inventory_dir}}/pki/dev-docker01/test')}}"
    {% endfor %}

    result
    "file content 01"
    "file content 01"
    "file content 01"
```

This one renders each host correctly as well

```
template.j2
{% for host in groups.docker_hosts %}
"{{host}}"
{% endfor %}

result:
"dev-docker01"
"dev-docker02"
"dev-docker03"
```

But as soon as i try using `host` inside file path i'm getting this error `"msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'host' is undefined"`

```
{% for host in groups.mongo_hosts %}
"{{lookup('file', '{{inventory_dir}}/pki/{{host}}/test')}}"
{% endfor %}
```

Seems like it's running in new isolate context which only has access to global variables. Any idea how to actually make it see `host` variable correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the value {{ host }} as name to the host. just use host as a variable.

```
{% for host in groups['webservers'] %}
"{{ lookup('file', 'test/' + host + '/foo.txt') }}"
{% endfor %}
```